# "Their windows slot the ebony of their walls with lemon." What's the meaning of this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, paragraphs

What is the meaning of the italicized sentence in this paragraph?

> From basement to sky rise the tenements of an alien colony. *Their windows slot the ebony of their walls with lemon.* Behind those windows, strange life is moving, dressed with forms that are not of London or of England, yet, in essence, the same agreeable life that you have been living, and tonight will live no more.

It's a part of the novel *"The hands of Mr. Ottermole"* by Thomas Burke.

Comment: Why the downvotes? Aside from the horrendous formatting (which has been fixed), it seems like a good question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's describing the pattern of colors of the wall and windows. The meaning of the word "slot" is "a small, narrow opening". In this sentence "ebony" means "black" and "lemon" means "yellow", so you can read the sentence as "the yellow of the windows looked like slots on the black wall". Does this help?